# After opening C# script in Visual Studio it shows up as in normal notepad

Tags: c#, visual-studio, performance, notepad

I had a problem with miscellaneous files and wanted to do something with it. Unfortunetly it turned out even worse and right now my visual studio looks more like notepad (no clues, no colors as shown on the photo below). Maybe someone had simillar issue?[Screenshot below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LxK6.png)

Comment: You sure have to check Unity kit in visual code for unity code.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth checking Options -> File Editor -> File extensions and confirm that you don't have Script Editor set for cs files.

[image]